# Problem with prime and unicode-math package

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

Here is a minimal code sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[ E'_1 \]
\end{document}
```

Without unicode-math package, I get this (good looking) result.

[image: good]

But with unicode-math package, I get this (not so good looking) result.

[image: bad]

There may be a relation with [this](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/503) issue, but is there a way to skirt this problem ?

Comment: I have tried your example on *overleaf* with and without the `unicode-math` package. In both cases I get the  first output!

Comment: That's a bug in the current fontspec (https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/349). It should be resolved in a few days, I get the correct result when using the development code.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was expecting a unicode-math issue.

Comment: Sorry everyone. New version of fontspec sent to CTAN that should fix this.

Comment: Ok, so I'm waiting for the Texlive update.